# $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ c.d.f. and quantile

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, normal-distribution, quantile-function

It is often useful to estimate the quantile for $\Phi^{-1}(d)$ for some real number $d$.
Here $\Phi\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
We cannot use for some unknown reasons the Taylor expansion as for estimating say $e^x$,
and we have to use a table occurring at the end of some books as an appendix.
I would like to be sure that there is no way around this.

**EDIT**

This doesn't look like $$\Phi^{-1}(d):$$

[image]

It's written in Maple.
What's wrong here ? **Even this is not OK**

[image]

Comment: Most programming languages or Excel et.al. provide that function.

Comment: @KurtG. Right, I just wanted to be self-sufficient with an old calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Phi^{-1}(d) = \sqrt2\,\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(2d - 1)\qquad \text{for} \qquad d\in(0,1)$$

What we can do is to build a $[2n+1,2n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$ around $d=\frac 12$ and obtain for example
$$\color{blue}{\Phi^{-1}(d) \sim x \,\, \frac{111547 x^4-1846740 x^2+3643920}{307995 x^4-2454060 x^2+3643920}}\qquad \color{red}{x=\sqrt{2 \pi } \left(d-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

Computing the norms,
$$\Psi_n(\epsilon)=\int_{\frac \epsilon {100}}^{1-\frac \epsilon {100}} \Big[\Phi^{-1}(d) -P_n\Big]^2\, dd$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
n & \epsilon=0& \epsilon=1 & \epsilon=2 & \epsilon=3 & \epsilon=4 & \epsilon=5  \\
 1 & 1.7\times 10^{-2} & 4.2\times 10^{-3} & 1.8\times
   10^{-3} & 8.7\times 10^{-4} & 4.5\times 10^{-4} &
   2.4\times 10^{-4} \\
 2 & 5.8\times 10^{-3} & 4.9\times 10^{-4} & 1.2\times
   10^{-4} & 3.4\times 10^{-5} & 1.1\times 10^{-5} &
   4.0\times 10^{-6} \\
 3 & 2.8\times 10^{-3} & 7.2\times 10^{-5} &
   8.7\times 10^{-6} & 1.5\times 10^{-6} & 3.1\times
   10^{-7} & 7.2\times 10^{-8} \\
 4 & 1.6\times 10^{-3} & 1.2\times 10^{-5} & 7.1\times
   10^{-7} & 7.1\times 10^{-8} & 9.1\times 10^{-9} &
   1.4\times 10^{-9} \\
 5 & 1.1\times 10^{-3} & 1.9\times 10^{-6} &
  6.0\times 10^{-8} & 3.4\times 10^{-9} & 2.8\times
   10^{-10} & 2.8\times 10^{-11} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

For the generation of $P_n$,
$$x=\sqrt{2 \pi } \left(d-\frac{1}{2}\right)\implies \Phi^{-1}(d) = \sqrt2\,\text{erf}^{-1}\left(x \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \right)$$
`P[n_]:=FullSimplify[PadeApproximant[Sqrt[2]*InverseErf[x*Sqrt[2/Pi]],{x, 0, {2*n+1, 2*n}}]]`

For the remaining

`Q[n_]:=Limit[P[n],x->Sqrt[2*Pi]*(d-1/2)]`

`Psi[n_]:=NIntegrate[(Sqrt[2]*InverseErf[2d-1]-Q[n])^2,{d,0.05,0.95}]`

Comment: There I some typos in your (promising) answer I believe. In the 4th line haven't you changed $d$ to $x$ ? So we still need to compute this integral by "hands", right ? Finally how have you computed this thing after $\sim x \frac{G}{H}$ ?

Comment: I do not understand : when I compute the norm, I replace $x$ by its definition. There is nothing to compute : just apply the colored formulae.

Comment: I see now. How have you obtained $\Phi^{-1}(d)$ Is there some general rule how to obtain this fraction depending on the number $4$- the exponent in the leading coefficient (if this is equal to 8, e.g.)? How have you obtained this particular fraction ? Is possible some numerical approach to compute the $\int_{0.05}^{0.95}$ ?

Comment: Please, see also my **EDIT**.

Comment: @user122424. Please do not add comment inside an answer. I shall clarify the genaration of how to generate the Padé approximant. For the computation of the norm, just use `NIntegrate`

Comment: Is your $$x=\sqrt{2 \pi } \left(d-\frac{1}{2}\right)\implies \Phi^{-1}(d) = \sqrt2\,\text{erf}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x\frac{2}{\pi }} \right)$$ correct ? Shouldn't it be $$x=\sqrt{2 \pi } \left(d-\frac{1}{2}\right)\implies \Phi^{-1}(d) = \sqrt2\,\text{erf}^{-1}\left(x\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \right)$$ ?

Comment: @user122424. Yes, it IS a typo

Comment: OK. Why didn't you integrate from $0$ to $1$ ? How can one derive $$\Phi^{-1}(d) = \sqrt2\,\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(2d - 1)\qquad \text{for} \qquad d\in(0,1)$$ ? Finally, I have tried to draw your $P_2$ and $P_4$ but it has no asymptotes at $-1$ and $1$ it just crosses that line $x=1$. Is this a gerenal property of Pade approximation ?

Comment: @user122424. I made it on purpose because there is no way to reproduce the vertical parts. I added number for different bounds.

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**. Something is wrong with your equation $$\Phi^{-1}(d) = \sqrt2\,\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(2d - 1)\qquad \text{for} \qquad d\in(0,1)$$